# JavaScript redirect script if domain name does not match my word

Tags: javascript

I want to put in my HTML/PHP a script for redirection if the website name does not match my word. I tried to use this code, but it doesn't work.

WITH REGEX

```
if (window.location.hostname !== 'myword.org'){
    window.top.location.href = 'http://redirecttomysite.org'; 
}

var website = window.location.hostname;
var internalLinkRegex = new RegExp('^((((http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)(www\\.)?)?'
                                     + website
                                     + ')|(localhost:\\d{4})|(\\/.*))(\\/.*)?$', '');
```

WITHOUT REGEX

```
if (website !== 'myword.org'){
    window.top.location.href = 'http://redirecttomysite.org/forum'; 
}
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I removed the PHP and HTML tags, as this appears to be dealing strictly with JavaScript. The fact that it's in an HTML page generated by PHP isn't directly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (website.indexOf('myword.org') == -1){
    window.top.location.href = 'http://redirecttomysite.org/forum'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("myword.org") == -1) {
       window.location = 'http://redirecttomysite.org';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply as below

```
if (!(/stackoverflow\.com/i.test(location.hostname))){
...
```

similar behavior as an HTTP redirect

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

similar behavior as clicking on a link

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```